# How do I run the same test case in 2 different URL which has same functionality in selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm new to selenium, can anyone help me on how to run the same test case in 2 different URL which has the same functionality

Comment: don't harcode the url as part of your testcase. instead read the url from some property file based on test environment type. Use different properties file for each environment ,that way you can reuse same test case.

Answer (score 0):

Two  ways you can do it.

1) Passing value from **xml** in **testng file**.

Test code you can refer.

```
public class ParameterTest
{
    @Parameters({ "url" })
    @Test
    public void optionTest(String value) {
        System.out.println("This is: " + value);
    }
}

<suite name="Optional test Suite" verbose="1">

  <test name="Optional Test one">
<parameter name="url" value="https://xy.cm" />
    <classes>
      <class name="test.parameter.OptionalTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Optional Test two">
    <parameter name="url" value="https://abc.om" />
    <classes>
      <class name="test.parameter.OptionalTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

2) You can use **data provider** in **testng** to pass url as parameter in your test case.

```
public class SameClassDataProvider
{
    @DataProvider(name = "url")
    public Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
        return new Object[][] { { "https://yahoo.com" }, { "https://google.in" } };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "data-provider")
    public void testMethod(String url) {
       //write your test case
 }
}
```

Hope this help you!